# Adding Error Handlers In VB

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

```
  ' Button which allows the user to enter in there own password
    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click


        Try
            If TextBox3.Text & TextBox6.Text & TextBox7.Text & TextBox8.Text > 0 And TextBox4.Text <> "" Then
                'input in these textboxes must be numerical
                ' It adds the passwords which is made by the user himself 
                ListBox1.Items.Add("Application : " & TextBox4.Text & " Password : " & TextBox3.Text & TextBox6.Text & TextBox7.Text & TextBox8.Text & " Time : " & TimeString & " Date : " & DateTime.Today)

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Please provide correct input")


        End Try
```

I'm currently making a password generator on visual basic , i have displayed the code in the part where the user can make there own password , however i wish to have some error handlers , currently i have got it working so a error message is displayed if non numeric information is entered into textbox3,6,7,8 . this works , however i wish to add two things 
1. An error message if textboxes3,6,7,8 are empty 
2. An error message if textbox4 is empty , curently nothing is printed in the listbox but no error message is displayed.

P.S 
A beginner to vb

Comment: The code in the snippet is nonsensical.  But valid syntax when you use the "anything goes" compile option.  Consider programming with Option Strict On for a while so the compiler can help you get this right.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need exception handling for validation. You can use the built in methods to do this.

For example the following checks if a texbox called ExampleTextBox has input and the input is a valid integer.

```
 If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ExampleTextBox.Text) Then
   'no input
 Else
   'has input, check if number
    Dim enteredNumber As Integer

    If Integer.TryParse(ExampleTextBox.Text, enteredNumber) Then
       'input is a valid integer
    Else
       'input is not a valid integer
    End If

End If
```

Comment: I'm sure you can adapt this to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make sense:

```
If TextBox3.Text & TextBox6.Text & TextBox7.Text & TextBox8.Text > 0 And TextBox4.Text <> "" Then
```

Say out loud what you want and build it up one piece at a time.  You want to display a message if `TextBox3` is empty:

```
If TextBox3.Text = String.Empty Then
```

You want to display a message if `TextBox3` or TextBox6 is empty:

```
If TextBox3.Text = String.Empty OrElse TextBox6.Text = String.Empty Then
```

Etc, etc.